# How can I build parameter (string) array from its parent object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

Let's say I've got an object defined by my model (using Rails 3) :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :List
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :age, presence: true
end
```

For some given object User, how can I build an array of string [name]?
Like:

```
ids = 1 , 2 , 3
Array.new (User.find_all_by_id(ids).name)
```

Would have:

Names[] = ["John" , "Bob" , "Tom"] 
Any Ideas?

Comment: What is `o` supposed to be? It is supposed to be a model, or an object that has been retrieved by your model?

Comment: What "path of object1" supposed to mean? Is it an attribute of the object?

Comment: Please add more details

Comment: i added more details + an example , hope that will make more sense :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at pluck:

```
ids = [1,2,3]    
User.where(id: ids).pluck(:name)
```

You can pass an array into a where condition, and pluck simply returns just the columns you need and returns an array

Comment: thanks , thumbs up please I think that can be useful for others :)

Answer (score 1):

To get an array of names from `User` model for a specific list of ids, you can use

```
User.where(id: ids).pluck(:name)
```

where `ids = [1,2,3]`

which will result in a query

```
SELECT "users"."name" FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: @xlembouras I guess I was typing in sleep.Thanks for fixing the typo. I had to look twice to figure out what exactly you fixed. :)

Answer (score 0):

`o.find_all_by_id(ids)` will return you an array.

o.where(id: ids) in Rails 4 style

Comment: This is Rails 3.x style.